# Why is "Nagios Not Running" in availability report 0 when alert log shows it down for long period

Tags: nagios

Back in February our nagios host was shut down for almost 40 minutes.

From my alert log:

```
[02-06-2013 13:39:54] Nagios 3.4.4 starting... (PID=3687)
[02-06-2013 13:01:17] Caught SIGTERM, shutting down...
```

However looking at availability reports for this time period (e.g. 1st Feb -> 28th Feb) the row "Nagios Not Running" is set to "0d 0h 0m 0s 0.000%".

In fact the entire "Undetermined" block is set to 0%.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Although it was 3.4.4 back in Feb, we are now running 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Got [a reply from Andreas Ericsson on nagios-users](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=5182E3D2.80408@op5.se&forum_name=nagios-users).

Nagios is guessing whether the services are up or not because I left the "Assume States During Program Downtime" option as its default 'Yes' rather than swapping it.

The url parameter if you're accessing directly is

> assumestatesduringnotrunning=no